# What possessed the Channelers in the Pokémon Tower?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

In the Pokémon Tower in Lavender Town, there are a number of Channelers who are eager for a Pokémon battle. When they approach you, they usually make an insane gibberish sound. After defeating them, they apologize and tell you that they were possessed.

But what actually possessed them? Was it their Pokémon? Or something else? Not sure if I missed a line of dialog in the game or if this is just a mystery.

Comment: @KazWolfe I'm not sure I understand the removal of the FireRed/LeafGreen tag, as this is a story question that involves both the first-gen games and the remakes.

Comment: Eh, just my method of tagging posts. As it's not specific to the FrLg games, it doesn't seem fitting for that tag. Feel free to add it back if you want to, though.

Comment: This seems unlikely, but perhaps they're just pretending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game itself has no lore pointing as to exactly *what* is possessing the Channelers.

However, it seems likely that the incorporeal culprits are the Pokemon the Channelers are using to fight. It is already known that some Pokemon [don't like being under a Trainer's control](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Pikachu). It's a safe assumption that the Gastlies don't like being captured either, and are "lashing out" at the Channelers whose very job is to channel spirits.

Similarly, another possible theory is that it's no particular Pokemon (or it's the Marowak Ghost in the tower). Either way, these Pokemon Spirits are/were riled up due to the recent influx of Team Rocket and their message of evil<sup>[citation-needed]</sup>. Alternatively, the Spirits could be protesting the treatment of kindly [Mr. Fuji](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mr._Fuji), who was captured by Team Rocket. Again, these Spirits would go through the Channelers who already open themselves up to our etherial battling pets.

Although, both of the above answers are speculation and are just theories on the game. The game itself makes no direct reference to who/what the Channelers were possessed by, leaving it up to the Player to decide. Both possible explanations have their evidences and pitfalls, leading us to believe that there is no true answer.

Comment: Seeing as the Channelers 'wake up' after you've battled them it's highly likely they are possessed by the (now fainted) Pokemon they fought you with.

Comment: @Robotnik Alternatively, whichever Spirit is possessing them thinks "This Channeler is worthless. Team Bloody Rocket and a Child for Ho-Oh's sake! Can she beat anyone?!"

Comment: @Robotnik That does seem like a likely conclusion, although it brings up the question of why other trainers can safely handle Ghost-type Pokémon. Or is Agatha of the Elite Four secretly possessed as well?